# How to pass multiple string values to checkbox?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a bus seat booking system, the problem is getting booked seat values from 'seat' column table name called as 'booking', here all the values are inserted using implode(',', $seat) method so if I pass the one value into view it will show the booked seat but if pass multiple string it wont show. I know it is a string, so there is any other way to do that? array didn't work for me.

Insert

```
$booking = new Bookings();
$booking->users_id = 4;
$booking->schedules_id = $schedules_id;
$booking->buses_id = $buses_id;
$booking->routes_id = $routes_id;
$booking->seat = implode(',', $seat);
$booking->price = $request->price;
$booking->profile = 'pending';
```

Collect

```
$seat = $request->seat;
$buses_id = $request->buses_id;
$schedules_id = $request->schedules_id;
$data = Buses::where('buses_id', $buses_id)->first();
$seat = json_decode($data->seat_layout, true);
$front = json_decode($data->front_layout, true);
$bookingSeat = Bookings::where('schedules_id', $schedules_id)->get();

return view('frontend.booking', ['seat' => $seat, 'buses_id' => $buses_id, 'schedules_id' => $schedules_id, 'front' => $front, 'bookingSeet'=>$bookingSeat]);
```

blade.php

```
<div class="bus">
  @foreach($seat as $key => $item)
  @foreach($bookingSeet as $seer)
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="seats back seats 
      @if($item['name'] == $seer['seat'])
      activeSeat
      @endif"
      data-id="{{$key}}">
        <div class="special-attributes"></div>
        @if(isset($item['name'])){{$item['name']}}@else 11A @endif

       <input type="checkbox" name="seat_id[]" id="{{$key}}" value="{{$key}}">

      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the POST seat is an array and you save it as an implode string,

so in the fetch iterate all the booking seats and explode it back to array

```
$bookingSeat = Bookings::where('schedules_id', $schedules_id)->get();
$bookingSeat = $bookingSeat->map(function($bookSeat) {
      $bookSeat->seat = explode(",", $bookSeat->seat);
      return $bookSeat;
});
```

and then in the blade check if the seat is in_array

```
@if(in_array($item['name'], $seer['seat']))
```

Comment: ur answer works for me but prb is when I insert new value it will creating a new row but I used updateOrCreate ('schedules_id' => $schedules_id) method but now existing data replaced by new data how to solve that?

Comment: it depent on your needs and in your table structure ... 1) first you can check if this specific schedules_id already exists in Bookings tabke on not, and then decide if ot insert or update. 2) OR you can always delete by schedules_id and then insert.

Comment: yes if schedules_id already exists need to merge old and new data into one column i tried some ways but it will replacing exists data with new one

Answer (score 0):

You are `implode`-ing the seats into a string but you are not `explode`-ing them before passing them to your front-end. I *assume* that this line should be changed to work as expected:

```php
$bookingSeat = explode(',', Bookings::where('schedules_id', $schedules_id)->get());
```

But I wonder why you have two loops rather than one:

1. The first loop should display all available seats in the bus (which is correct)
2. The second loop is looping over all bookings, but this is done per available seat in the bus (which is unnecessary/in-correct)

Instead you should check if a seat has been reserved and remove your second loop:

```php
 @if(in_array($item['name'], bookingSeet))
     <input type="checkbox" name="seat_id[]" id="{{$key}}" value="{{$key}}" checked="checked">
 @else
     <input type="checkbox" name="seat_id[]" id="{{$key}}" value="{{$key}}">
 @endif
```